# Align a to-do list with two columns

Tags: spacing

I am trying to make a simple to-do list where on the left-hand side I would have checkboxes and some text and on the right side horizontal lines aligned with the bottom of the current line. Currently, the lines have a tighter spacing than the checkbox list.

[image]

For some reason, the `\parskip` and `\baselineskip` do not change the spacing, and most importantly, do not align the two sides.

Can someone help me fix it, please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{multido}
\newcommand{\drawline}{\noindent\rule{0.9\textwidth}{0.5pt}\par}
\newcommand{\Repeat}{\multido{\i=1+1}}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=25mm,
    headheight=27mm,
    footskip=8mm,
    bottom=20mm,
    right=12mm
    }

\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}% Change page style to fancy
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[L]{Checkliste Bewehrungseisen}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\hspace{1cm}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}


\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}

%%----------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{todolist}
            \item List item 1 goes here.
            \item List item 2 goes here.
                \begin{todolist}
                    \item Sublist item 1 goes here.
                    \item Sublist item 2 goes here.
                \end{todolist}
            \item List item 3 goes here
            \item List item 4 goes here.
        \end{todolist}
    \clearpage
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\vrule
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \Repeat{6}{\drawline}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I‘d try package hyperref, which provides checkboxes, which you can edit (select/deselect later). Use them in a table, e.g. to obtain the vertical and horizontal lines.

Comment: Do you know how to place the entire list into a table?

Comment: You can do it line by line, as in any table. Instead of using \items, you place the checkbox, with some horizontal indent, if you need (\hspace{} or similar).